# gtk-color-scheme = "bg_color: red\ results in red bg + red scroll bar bg + red scroll bar ? where is the logic?

Tags: configuration, theme, gtk2, gnome2

Let's edit this theme's gtkrc file:

```
vi vi /usr/share/themes/industrial/gtk-2.0/gtkrc

gtk-color-scheme = "bg_color: #000000000000\
nfg_color: #ffffff\nbase_color: #000000000000\
ntext_color: #ffffff\nselected_bg_color: #ffffff\
nselected_fg_color: #000000000000\
ntooltip_bg_color: #000000000000\
ntooltip_fg_color: #ffffff
```

Let's change the bg_color to "red" and apply the theme to the desktop.

But the problem is this, the background of every scroll bar, and the foreground of the scroll bar, both become red, this makes it impossible to see the scroll bar due to the background being same color as the scroll bar.

By scroll bar I am referring to the scroll bar in firefox web browser for example that you'd use to scroll up and down. I am currently using my mouse's wheel button because the scroll bar does not look visible.

Why are colors being applied this way? Why isn't there a distinction between the foreground and the background of the scroll bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element combination of a `RGB`, if you want to retrieve a `RGB` of `red` , `blue` or another `color`, you can open `gimp`, and choose `color` and retrieve the given  `RGB`.